# Unity Prevent spawning objects from overlapping 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, overlap, spawn

i have 3 of the same code below and was wondering what should i add to avoid all the objects from overlapping when spawned? Thanks in advance!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnObstacleGreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obstaclegreen;
    public float maxX;
    public float minX;
    public float maxY;
    public float minY;
    public float timeBetweenSpawn;
    private float spawnTime;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Time.time > spawnTime)
        {
            Spawn();
            spawnTime = Time.time + timeBetweenSpawn;
        }
    }

    void Spawn()
    {
        float randomX = Random.Range(minX,maxX);
        float randomY = Random.Range(minY,maxY);

        Instantiate(obstaclegreen, transform.position + new Vector3(randomX, randomY, 0), transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can test for overlaps with a `boxcast` and try agin, or try agin after pushing your dpawn coordinates away from the previous position in the direction, the two positions difference vector points to.

Comment: The problem of instantiating random non overlapping objects is a very common in games development in general. So just look up, there is plenty information on that, for example look here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/160718/instantiate-two-objects-at-random-non-overlapping-positions